# Incomplete code coverage after upgrading from Angular 5 to angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, istanbul, karma-coverage

I am upgrading my project from angular 5 to 6, I am able to build the project and run all the unit tests, but the code coverage report does not include coverage for all files.
My project is divided into 2 folders and 2 modules app.module and module for my application. There are 2 folders dev and src both at the root level. Dev folder contains the main.ts and app.module and src folder contains all the other components. After running ng test --code-coverage, the coverage report generated only shows coverage for files inside the dev folder, the report shows coverage for 3 files test.ts, polyfill.ts and app.component.ts, I have other components/services/directives in the src folder and the corresponding spec files, the tests are running for those spec files but there is no coverage generated for files under src folder.

This is my angular.json file test section contents

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "dev/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "dev/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "dev/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": [
          "dev/styles.scss"
        ],
        "assets": [
          "dev/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
```

Contents for test.ts

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context1 = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
const context = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
context1.keys().map(context1);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Contents of package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
"@northstar/shared-module": "^5.0.5",
"@types/faker": "^4.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
"@types/node": "^6.0.117",
"chai": "3.5.0",
"codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
"core-js": "^2.5.7",
"faker": "^4.1.0",
"htmlhint": "0.9.13",
"jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^3.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"karma-istanbul-threshold": "1.2.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
"karma-trx-reporter": "~0.2.9",
"ng-packagr": "^3.0.6",
"protractor": "^5.3.0",
"rimraf": "2.5.2",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"stylelint": "~8.4.0",
"stylelint-order": "~0.6.0",
"ts-node": "^5.0.1",
"tsickle": "^0.32.1",
"tslint": "^5.11.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"web-animations-js": "~2.3.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
```

Karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('karma-istanbul-threshold'),
        require('karma-trx-reporter'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    mime: {
        'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary', 'json'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    istanbulThresholdReporter: {
        src: 'coverage/coverage-final.json',
        reporters: ['text'],
        thresholds: {
            global: {
                statements: 80,
                branches: 65,
                functions: 80,
                lines: 80,
            },
            // **********For later **********//
            // each: {
            //  statements: 80,
            //  branches: 80,
            //  functions: 80,
            //  lines: 80,
            // },
        }
    },
    trxReporter: {
        outputFile: 'test/test-results.trx',
        shortTestName: false
    },

    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul','trx', 'istanbul-threshold']
        : ['progress', 'kjhtml','trx'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 95000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 30000,
    captureTimeout: 60000
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to supply the contents of your karma.conf.js file?

Comment: Updated the question with karma.conf.js

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to shed some light on why you have two folders dev and src rather than having it all under src?

Comment: The module defined in the src project is published to npm to be consumed by other modules, the dev has the app.module and main.ts to run the project as standalone application. This is the structure used by all our projects, I don't think changing the structure is an option for me.